# how to find thet a given real symmetric matrix is positive definite, positive semidefinite, negative definite, negative semidefinite or indefinite.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

How to find that a given real symmetric matrix is positive definite, positive semidefinite, negative definite, negative semidefinite or indefinite.; on the basis of principle diagonal minor.

Answer (score 2):

A real symmetric matrix $A$, is positive semidefinite iff all the principal minors of $A$ are nonnegative.

For the proof please [see](http://www.sfu.ca/~mdevos/notes/semidef/semidef_mat.pdf).